# NSString is not getting added to NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
-(IBAction)orderButtonPressed
{       
     myString = staterlabel1.text;
     [myArray addObject:myString];

     NSLog(@"wat is in  %@",myArray);       
}


-(IBAction)orderButton2Pressed
{           
     myString2  = staterlabel2.text;
     [myArray addObject:myString];
     NSLog(@"wat is in  %@",myArray);    
}
```

After clicking the button the text in the `myString` should add to the `NSMutableArray` object `myArray`, but this does not happen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo

```
(IBAction)orderButtonPressed
{       
     myString = staterlabel1.text;
     [myArray addObject:myString];

     NSLog(@"wat is in  %@",myArray);       
}


-(IBAction)orderButton2Pressed
{           
     myString2  = staterlabel2.text;
     [myArray addObject:myString2]; // <-- change here
     NSLog(@"wat is in  %@",myArray);    
}
```

In the second method you need to add `myString2` not `myString`

Comment: In your `orderButton2Pressed` method you are adding `myString` to the array instead of `myString2`